# css problemetic div position and overlaying

Tags: html, css

I need to code this innerpage: 
http://www.moonbingo.com/skin/promotions/2011/fairy-party.php

and for now I just posted it as an image.

I tried to work with divs but I had problems with the side baloons

I added the images I have cutted and the code.

the porblem is that text inside the XXX div should expand it containing div by its length,
and I want to position it some pixels abov' so it could start in the current place...

```
 <div>
        <div style="background-image: url('fairy-party-top.png'); width: 678px; height: 141px;"></div>



            <div style="background-image: url('fairy-party-body-top.png'); width: 677px; height: 45px;"></div>
            <div style="background-image: url('fairy-party-body-middle.png'); width: 650px; height: 100px; background-repeat: repeat-y;">
                <p style="display: inline-block; padding-top: 10px;">sdasdasasd</p>
            </div>




        <div style="background-image: url('fairy-party-body-bottom.png'); width: 667px; height: 225px;"></div>
    </div>
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try [position:absolute](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp) for the div with text.

Comment: tried position absolut for text, and for it's container position reletive. but it's looks bad...